# Yii2: Where is the right place I can add ini_set in my Yii2-advanced-app?

Tags: php, precision, yii2-advanced-app, ini-set

I've an application in my Apache local Server and using **Yii2-advanced-app**. I need to edit my php.ini to support my project, I need to change `precision=14` become `precision=20`. I'm affraid that change will affect all application in my local server. I've read some issue, and they said I can add `ini_set('precision', '20');` in my current application, so that change will only affect the current application.

In some issue they said in **Yii2-basic-app** you can add that in `web.php`, under `use` statement. I think that file in **Yii2-advanced-app** equal to `/config/main.php`. I didn't found any `use` statement there, and I also have add the `ini_set` in there and I got nothing.

#### Where is the right place I can add this `ini_set` code in my current application?

Comment: If you need this only in one of the applications (frontend or backend) you can add this in its entry script (`/web/index.php`). If you need this everywhere you can add it in `common/config/bootstrap.php`.

Comment: @Bizley thanks :D It work in `common/config/bootstrap.php`. I also try in controller which read float point, and it work :)

Comment: @Bizley Hei, Do you know where I've to add `ini_set` in yii2-basic template? Because I didn't find bootstrap.php in `config` dir. Thanks

Comment: Use entry script `/web/index.php`.

Comment: @Bizley Can you describe the code?

Comment: Which code? I don't understand.

Comment: @Bizley I got it :) That you mean entry script, I create file `bootstrap.php` that contain `ini_set`. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: I meant you can put ini_set in the entry script which is the file `/web/index.php`

Comment: @Bizley Ok, so I dont need to create bootsrap.php?

Comment: No, you don't have to do it.

Comment: @Bizley Yeah, you're right. It work :) thankyou

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use '[.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)' in your public directory.

Example of .user.ini:

```
precision = 20
memory_limit = 768M
post_max_size = 68M
```